# updating database when a product has been deducted

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Good Day everyone! 
I'm encountering a problem in deducting a quantity of my product in my database
Here's my code..

```vb
Dim intQty As Integer
Dim que As String

intQty = Convert.ToInt32(enterqtyfrm.txtqty.Text)

que = "UPDATE db_product SET Qty = Qty - '" & intQty & "' WHERE itemsName = '" & Home.lblOrderName.Text & "'"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `"I'm encountering a problem"` - That isn't particularly descriptive.  Maybe you could let us know what that problem *is*?  (Other than the SQL injection vulnerability you have, of course.)

Comment: What problem???

Comment: it didn't deduct the quantity in my database

Comment: remove the single quotes between inQty. It is a number not a char.

Comment: sounds like (gotta guess) `enterqtyfrm.txtqty.Text` is not numeric or not an int

Comment: I remove the single quotes but then  an error occurs in this line ..     intQty = Convert.ToInt32(enterqtyfrm.txtqty.Text)  says " Input string was not in a correct format."                                                                                                               sorry I'm a beginner in vb

Comment: What's the value of `enterqtyfrm.txtqty.Text`?

Comment: I meant to remove it in your sql `... Qty = Qty - " & intQty & " WHERE ...`

Answer (score 0):

You've got two separate problems here, 1 is that you're trying to concatenate an integer into a string. 2, your sql syntax for subtracting the quantity is incorrect. You don't need to convert the number to an integer to add it to a sql command, and you've gotta lose the single quotes:

```
If IsNumeric(enterqtyfrm.txtqty.Text) Then
    Dim que As String = "UPDATE db_product SET Qty = Qty - " & enterqtyfrm.txtqty.Text & " WHERE itemsName = '" & Home.lblOrderName.Text & "'"
    'execute que
End If
```

Sidenote: it's best practice to use parameters in your sql for a number of reasons, so I would recommend learning how to do that...there are plenty of SO posts on how to do that. Also, it would be a good idea to add some validation to the values that are getting concatenated into your sql string since the user could type in all kinds of different things that would break the statement.